# How can I change the default file type for "Save Selection As"

Tags: front-end

When using the menu item File - Save Selection As, the default file type is PDF. Is there any way to change the default to something else, for example PNG?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not aware of a programmatic way of doing this (other than programmatically opening/editing/saving this file) but you can do it by editing an internal file.

1. In a text editor open

   `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "TextResources", "CommonFrontEndInit.tr"}]`
2. Find `AddFileBrowserFilterPacket["SaveSelection", ...`
3. Change the order of the file types, e.g. to show PNG by default move PNG to the top of the list

[image]

4. Now the default will always be PNG

Comment: works well thanks +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've been wanting to make this change for a long time, but didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks Mike.